# "Activity has leaked window that was originally added here"

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-alertdialog

So below is my code,

```
public class Assignment_Create extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

DataManipulator dataManipulator;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 1;
AlertDialog.Builder dialogAc;

ImageView imageViewDateAssign, imageViewDueDate, imageViewSubmit;
TextView textViewDtAssign, textViewDueDt;
EditText editTextTitle, editTextDesc;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
int cDay, cMonth, cYear;

private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;

// Update database
String updateId;
public boolean isEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.assignment_create);

    imageViewDateAssign = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dateassign);
    imageViewDueDate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.duedate);
    imageViewSubmit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    textViewDtAssign = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDateAssign);
    textViewDueDt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDueDate);

    editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    editTextDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);

    isEdit = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isEdit");
    updateId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idNo");

    if (isEdit) {
        editTextTitle.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(
                "AsmntTitle"));
        editTextDesc
                .setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("AsmntDesc"));
    }

    Code.AssignDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Code.DueDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    imageViewDateAssign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDateDialog(textViewDtAssign, Code.AssignDate);
        }
    });

    imageViewDueDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDateDialog(textViewDueDt, Code.DueDate);
        }
    });

    imageViewSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateDisplay(textViewDtAssign, Code.AssignDate);
    updateDisplay(textViewDueDt, Code.DueDate);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.submit:

        Code.title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        Code.description = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        Code.diff = Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis()
                - Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis();
        Code.days = Code.diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        Code.strDays = String.valueOf(Code.days);

        if (isEdit) {
            this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
            this.dataManipulator.update(updateId);
            this.dataManipulator.close();
        } else {
            this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
            this.dataManipulator.insert(Code.title, Code.description,
                    Code.strDays);
            this.dataManipulator.close();
        }

        if (Code.title.length() <= 0 || Code.description.length() <= 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Assignment_Create.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not proper date",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Details are saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Assignment Created Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Assignment_Create.this.finish();
        break;
    }
}

private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
    activeDate = date;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);

        unregisterDateDisplay();
    }
};

private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
    activeDateDisplay = null;
    activeDate = null;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener,
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Everything work's fine but when i leave both edit-text empty it should show alert-dialog but instead of this it is giving error of Activity has leaked window.

Below is my logcat...

```
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940): Activity iqualtech.skirr.Assignment_Create has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420cf5b0 that was originally added here
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity iqualtech.skirr.Assignment_Create has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420cf5b0 that was originally added here
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:268)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at iqualtech.skirr.Assignment_Create.onClick(Assignment_Create.java:132)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-24 11:32:55.995: E/WindowManager(1940):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried with some of the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=activity+has+leaked+windows+in+android

but i am not getting what do i need to chage and where exactly. I just want to show alert dialog on submit button click event if both the edit-text is empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to finish `Assignment_Create` after click dialog ok and cancel

Comment: Means inside alert dialog onClick event i need to finish my activity..

Comment: @Tamilselvan, what???

Comment: yes, you need to do like that,

Comment: @SathishKumar, i have added Assignment_Create.this.finish(); inside Ok and Cacel button onclick method but no change. Still not getting alert dialog.

Comment: do you get solution from GLee answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call `Assignment_Create.this.finish();` directly after calling `dialog.show()`.  This means that the dialog is on screen when your activity gets destroyed, which causes the leaked window exception.  You need to close all dialogs by calling `dialog.dismiss()` before calling `this.finish()`.

You have two options:

1. Move `this.finish()` to inside your `onClickListene`r for the
   alert dialog.  This is what I think you want, so that the activity
   will finish only if the user clicks ok in the dialog.
2. Call `alertdialog.finish()` directly before calling `this.finish()`.

Comment: Sorry if this is silly question, what changes i have to do as per my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assignment_Create.this.finish();
```

Above statement will lead to destruction of activity but your alert dialog is still open.

You need to make sure that before destroying your activity your alert dialog needs to be closed. This way you can prevent this exception.

Possible solution:

1. You can dismiss your dialog box in onDestroy() of activity.

I think you want to finish in some particular case, but currently finish is valid for all cases in R.id.submit.

Answer (score 0):

remove Assignment_Create.this.finish();